# view javascript object change using BackBone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I have an object:

```
NAMESPACE.SOMEOBJECT.VALUE = 0
```

Some other foreign script owns and changes that value based on an event that I don't have access to. I know that the value is changed by different events on different pages. I can't edit the .js that controls that object. Does anyone have any idea how i can listen to that specific object and then run a function if that value changes?

I cannot add a new library or any external script. I'm using Backbone, require.js and jQuery.

If I were to use a backbone.model and add a reference to this object in my model, and then in my view I were to listenTo my model, would that tell me if that object has been updated? If so, sow would I go about doing this?

I DO have access to an ID on the page that allows me to access a DIV that has the value that I'm looking for. Keep in mind, that every time my object value updates, I need to know if it's been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to 'add a reference to this object in the model' as this is just another way of saying that something should 'listen' for changes on the object. In order for a model to trigger a `change` event, one of its attributes has to change and this cannot happen by any means other than calling the model's `set` method or (re-)fetching (changed) data from the server-side.

How about polling the object instead of listening for an event? You could use `setInterval` to periodically query the relevant value and track its changes. In the event that the value *has* changed you can invoke the desired behaviour.

You could also wrap this functionality in a Backbone model if this is a good fit for your app's design: In the [model's initialize / constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) use `setInterval` to start polling the value periodically and use `set` to copy it onto one of the model's attributes. Backbone will take care of tracking state for you and the model will trigger a `change` event if (and only if) the value changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is exactly what I thought but wanted to avoid. Thanks for the answer!